# learning rust, trying to build a middle ware function in actix_web 4.3.1

Tags: rust, actix-web

i tried the doc, but that does only give either a very complex use case or an inline function with no types....
there are a lot of questions around this, also tutorials on the web, but that won't work with the actix version i have....

i want to check the presence of a jwt token in the header, and if its valid as jwt and valid locally pass on the request, otherwise redirect to the login page....

the middleware stuff looks like way over my paygrade and total overkill for this, the wrap_fn function like use case much more abordable....

at the moment i am trying to make an empty passthrough, and fail at it....

i tried:

```
    use actix_service::Service;
    use actix_web::dev::{ServiceRequest, ServiceResponse};
    use actix_web::Error;
    use futures::future::{ok, Ready};

    pub async fn my_middleware(
   req: ServiceRequest,
   srv: &mut (dyn Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse, Error = Error, Future = Ready<Result<ServiceResponse, Error>>> + 'static),
   ) -> Result<ServiceResponse, Error> {
     srv.call(req).await 
  }
```

this fails with the following error:

```
  --> src/users/routes.rs:207:22
   |
207 |               .wrap_fn(users::middleware::my_middleware)
   |                ------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected due to this
   |                |
   |                required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
  ::: src/users/middleware.rs:6:1
   |
6   | / pub async fn my_middleware(
7   | |     req: ServiceRequest,
8   | |     srv: &mut (dyn Service<
9   | |         ServiceRequest,
...   |
13  | |     > + 'static),
14  | | ) -> Result<ServiceResponse, Error> {
   | |___________________________________- found signature defined here
   |
   = note: expected function signature `for<'a> fn(ServiceRequest, &'a actix_web::scope::ScopeService) -> _`
              found function signature `for<'a> fn(ServiceRequest, &'a mut (dyn actix_service::Service<ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse, Error = actix_web::Error, Future = futures::future::Ready<Result<ServiceResponse, actix_web::Error>>> + 'static)) -> _`
note: required by a bound in `actix_web::Scope::<T>::wrap_fn`
  --> /home/bboett/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/actix-web-4.3.1/src/scope.rs:356:12
   |
356 |         F: Fn(ServiceRequest, &T::Service) -> R + Clone + 'static,
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `Scope::<T>::wrap_fn`
```

So somehow, instead of the expected ServiceResponse i have to change the type to ScopeService, which i can't seem to find, so what would be the right type for this function?